# 'ProfileForm' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django. I have a model Profile:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    skillstolearn = models.TextField()
    skillstoteach = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

And a form ProfileForm:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user', 'city', 'country', 'skillstolearn', 'skillstoteach', 'description']
```

I'm trying to use the view below...

```
def profileupdate(request):
    profile = ProfileForm(request.POST)
    current = Profile.objects.get(user=profile.user.username)
    print(current)
    if profile.is_valid():
        print('is valid')
    else:
        print('is not valid')
    return redirect('/thecode/userpage')
```

...to figure out if a user already exists, because I want to use the same form for both creating and updating.

I get the error message "'ProfileForm' object has no attribute 'user'".

How do I get the result for user that has been sent in the form?

Update: below are the error messages that I get

```
Internal Server Error: /thecode/profileupdate/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/phershbe/Desktop/socialnetwork/theproject/thecode/views.py", line 45, in profileupdate
    current = Profile.objects.get(user_id=profile.user.id)
AttributeError: 'ProfileForm' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you making get from Profile's table `current = Profile.objects.get(user=profile.user.username)` you are comparing `user` (an instance of User) with `username` (which is string).
So you need to choose a needed variant of how to do it:

1)

```
current = Profile.objects.get(user=profile.user)
```

2. 

```
current = Profile.objects.get(user__username=profile.user.username)
```

3. 

```
current = Profile.objects.get(user_id=profile.user.id)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but all of those gave me the same error.

Comment: could you add all the stack traces in your message

Comment: I added the errors which were given. Probably also there is a more conventional way to use the same form for creating and updating, but I was having trouble finding a solution.

Comment: ok, let's see what you have in request.POST["user"], print it right after function definition

Comment: With request.POST["user"], the id of the user comes up, which probably allows me to then check if there is a Profile associated with the user huh?